# In OpenAPI, when using OAuth 2.0, how do you describe the exact mechanism that should be used to authorize requests to a resource server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, access-token, openapi

Let's say a client, which is our trusted BFF (backend for frontend), uses the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) to obtain an access token by requesting an authorization server's `/token` endpoint. Further, the following *usually* happens - the client sends the `Authorization: Bearer access_token` header with each request to the resource server, and the resource server uses the received token to decide whether to authorize the request. There are other options, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-7 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-8.1 for details.

However, access tokens may be either "bearer tokens" or "sender-constrained" tokens. Or they may even be some special proprietary tokens. OpenAPI only allows you to specify an OAuth security scheme type and a list of scopes required to request an endpoint (resource server). It might look like this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oAuthSample:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: https://api.example.com/oauth2/authorize
          scopes:
            read_pets: read pets in your account
            write_pets: modify pets in your account
```

```
paths:
  /pets/{petId}:
    patch:
      summary: Updates a pet in the store
      security: 
        - oAuthSample: [write_pets]
      ...
```

Source: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/.

How, from such a specification, you can understand how exactly a client should be authorized on a resource server on behalf of an user? Should it just be stated in a text documentation, or is there a standardized way provided by OpenAPI?

Or maybe it's better to formulate the question as follows - how in OpenAPI to specify the type of an access token from the options defined here https://www.iana.org/assignments/oauth-parameters/oauth-parameters.xhtml#token-types, that is issued by an authorization server and, as a result, explain how the token is used for authorization on a resource server?

Comment: Consider also asking in the OpenAPI Specification repo: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions/2867.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach I would aim for in a Swagger spec, to get the right kind of balance of responsibilities that would scale to a company with many APIs. There are many possible use cases though, so it may not be what you are looking for.

**API SECURITY DETAILS**

Each API just points to the discovery endpoint of the Authorization Server, to tell clients where to register:

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    openId:
      type: openIdConnect
      openIdConnectUrl: https://login.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

And each API indicates the scopes needed to call its endpoints:

```yaml
paths:
  /pets/{petId}:
  patch:
    oauth2:
      scope: pets_write
```

**CLIENT REGISTRATION**

An OAuth client needs to be registered at the Authorization Server (AS), which sits alongside APIs and is typically administered by the people who own the data / APIs. The type of token issued to the client would also be configured here.

For a web client this might result in the following details being provided:

- ClientID: myclientid
- Client Secret: myclientsecret
- Redirect URI: https://oauth.tools/callback/code

**CLIENT / USER AUTHENTICATION**

The people who implement the client would then need to implement an OAuth flow, and for a web client the Authorization Code Flow is standard. Libraries implementing this will usually look up front and back channel endpoints from the discovery endpoint. Before beginning coding though, tooling can be used to rehearse the process, eg:

- Browse to [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools)
- Select `Environments / New Environment`
- Type in the discovery URL and click Discover
- Make sure that the new environment is selected
- Then select Code Flow
- Then enter the Client ID, Client Secret and scope

[image]

If you have an Authorization Server you should be able to get this working end-to-end. Click `Run` to do the redirect, do a user login, then scroll down and click `Redeem Code` to get tokens.

**ACCESS TOKENS**

The client just receives a string access token and sends it to the API. This is either an opaque reference token such as a UUID, or a JWT. Even in financial-grade setups with sender constrained tokens, bearer tokens are used, as in [this client script](https://github.com/curityio/mutual-tls-api-example/blob/main/4-run-test-client.sh), which sends tokens down a Mutual TLS channel. Usage of other types of tokens are very rare indeed, so I would not spend time on them unless you have special requirements.

**SUMMARY**

I would aim to keep the OpenAPI / Swagger spec fairly simple. Personally I don't think an API should need to know which clients use which flows, and that using the discovery URL is cleaner - it also potentially gives the client more choices.

Comment: I understand how different flows work in OAuth 2.0, my question is about something else. The client always receives an access token. Access tokens are different. How does the OpenAPI specification, in accordance with its rules, specify how a client (and the OpenAPI specification is created primarily in order to use it to integrate clients with API) should be authorized when accessing API endpoints, which in OAuth 2.0 terms is called "server resources".

P.S. The OAuth 2.0 standard does not contain such a thing as a "gateway", the use of gateway is optional when implementing OAuth 2.0 flows.

Comment: OK - updated my answer after thinking a little more about this. It is a while since I worked with Swagger docs and I have just provided my thoughts on what would make sense for clients, since I do a lot of explaining client flows in my job.

Comment: So, you suggest that in the `authorizationUrl` parameter, instead of an URL to the endpoint to receive an authorization grant, specify discovery endpoint from the OIDC standard, and at the same time allow a client itself to find out exactly how (how?) it should present an access token received from an authorization server to a resource server? But that doesn't answer my question, it's related to the OIDC standard, it violates the OpenAPI spec, which assumes that the `authorizationUrl` parameter points to the [authorization endpoint](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.1).

Comment: You said: "If an endpoint requires special types of token such as DPoP or Certificate Bound Access Tokens then it could be indicated in the scheme above.". How exactly to do that?

Comment: "I would aim to keep the OpenAPI / Swagger spec fairly simple." - I agree. "Personally I don't think an API should need to know which clients use which flows." - I agree, and it's not my question. But clients and/or developers who intergrate clients with APIs should somehow know how to request endpoints, right? Right, and how exactly a client should authorize itself when requesting an endpoint should be specified somewhere. It doesn't seem to be possible with the OpenAPI spec, so it should just be specified in text docs. Here is the answer.